# How can automate a specific process of importing, editing, and exporting scenes?

Tags: python, scripting, export, import, gltf

I have some pre-existing GLTF scenes (or objects) that I've been using Blender to modify and re-format so that I can export them as .FBX scenes that Unreal Engine 4 can import properly.

While I've narrowed down the specific sequence of edits to make, and settings to use both on importing (GLTF) and exporting (FBX), it's becoming incredibly tedious and frustrating to do this over and over again.

I think there's a few ways to streamline this, like writing a script or i/o plugin, but I have no idea how to write or format such a thing. The official API documentation just did not click with me.

Comment: There is a free tutorial called _[Scripting for Artists](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists/)_ on Blender Cloud.  If you haven't yet, give it a try. Perhaps it will click better than the API documents

Comment: The glTF unit tests show an example of using Python scripting to import and export glTF files in Blender:  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/blob/master/tests/roundtrip_gltf.py